# Jail broken iOS: Communication between tweak and application

Tags: ios, ipc, jailbreak, tweak, cydia-substrate

I have my iOS application (standard application with legitimate configuration). It gets information about phone number from network and shows to user. Application can work with network, has storage and it's very clever :).
Also I have a tweak for InCallService.app that shows additional information about current call. I want this one to be very stupid and simple.
I need an advice how can I make communication between the tweak and the application. I want the application to be started by request from tweak in the background  mode, then loads information in background mode store received data and return this data to tweak. Data contains a lot of information and I'm not sure that all this information can be posted inside of URL.
Which technologies should I use? Also if it's possible any links to related subjects would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Pretty happy to find your question, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve! I'd like to know if you managed to do it, and if so, did you use `CPDistributedMessagingCenter` or `RocketBoostrap`? Thanks in advance 

Comment: Hi. I've done all I wanted, but unfortunately it was a long time ago. It was the first and the last application for JB phone I did. So now I'm out of the context. I'm afraid it will take some time to find that project and restore required information.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, no problem I totally understand. If by any means you found that project or remember if you used CPDMC or RocketBootsrap, don’t hesitate to tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPDistributedMessagingCenter is a popular option. It is a wrapper over the existing messaging facilities in the operating system. It provides server-client communication between different processes using simple messages and dictionaries. http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CPDistributedMessagingCenter

RocketBootstrap is another option. It is a library that solves a denied lookup error of IPC services on iOS 7 and above
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/RocketBootstrap